# This operation can only be performed on output buffers - SSIS Kingswaysoft error

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We have recently migrated to Visual Studio 2022 from Visual Studio 2014 , one of my package is failing in Visual Studio 2022 when trying to use the kingswaysoft data conversion tool stating "Premium Conversion [415]: An error occurred with the following error message: "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.NotOutputBufferException: This operation can only be performed on output buffers. (SSIS Productivity Pack, v23.2.0.25101 - DtsDebugHost, v16.0.1000.6)". Does anyone know how to resolve this issue. Our server spec is

Os - OS Name    Microsoft Windows Server 2022 Datacenter Azure Edition

Processor - Processor   AMD EPYC 7763 64-Core Processor, 2445 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)

RAM- 16 gb.

Any help on this error would be greatly appreciated.

Note - the same package works fine in VS 2014